# PHP : PDO fetch() not showing result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm now learning PDO I just followed the tutorial on Youtube. So here I have here a method from Db class and I added a new line PDO::FETCH_ASSOC because I want to try a while loop besides of foreach.

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
$this->_error = false;
$this->_count = 0;
if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){

  #check if theres a parameter and bindvalue to sql statement
  if(count($params)){
    $x = 1;
    foreach($params as $param){
      $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
      $x++;
    }
  }

  #execute with or without parameter
  if($this->_query->execute()){
    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->_whileFetch = $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
  }else{
    $this->_error = true;
  }
  return $this;
}
} #end of GET function


public function whileFetch(){
   return $this->_whileFetch;
}
```

The foreach is working well, but I want to try a while loop but it seems not working, not showing any data.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * from master_data.store");
while($row = $query->whileFetch()){
     echo $row['name'];
}
```

I also try this, but i got error.

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of this method call `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`. Since you're fetching all the rows from the result set as an array and assigning it to the instance variable `$results`, this statement `$this->_whileFetch = $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` won't work afterwards. And that's why you'll have `$this->_whileFetch` as `false`.

So the solution is,

- Remove the instance variable `$_whileFetch` from your class, you won't be needing this.
- Remove the following two lines from this `if($this->_query->execute()){ ... }` block,

  ```
  $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $this->_whileFetch = $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```
- In the `whileFetch()` method, instead of `$this->_whileFetch`, directly fetch the next row from the result set and return it,

  ```
  return $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```

So your `query()` and `whileFetch()` method would be like this:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    $this->_count = 0;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        #check if theres a parameter and bindvalue to sql statement
        if(count($params)){
            $x = 1;
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        #execute with or without parameter
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else{
            $this->_error = true;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

public function whileFetch(){
    return $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Later, you can have your query and `while()` loop like this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * from master_data.store");
while($row = $query->whileFetch()){
     echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did but I can only call once each of the while loop or foreach and the next loop is not working anymore

Comment: @RaffyTLawrence Yes, That's because once you're done iterating the result set using `while` loop, the result set will be exhausted. You cannot adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set again. So use either `while` or `foreach` loop to loop through the result set.

Comment: @RaffyTLawrence Having said this, in case you want to loop through the result set *again*, you need to set PDO cursor to `CURSOR_SCROLL`. By default it's set to `CURSOR_FWDONLY`. Take a look at this SO thread, and the *accepted* answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/15637291/5517143](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15637291/5517143)

Answer (score 1):

This is an awful tutorial and your class has some critical drawbacks as a result. Your function should be looking like this

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

So you'll be able to use whatever method supported by PDO:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * from master_data.store");
foreach($query as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
}

$query = $db->query("SELECT * from master_data.store");
while($row = $query->fetch()){
    echo $row['name'];
}

$list = $db->query("SELECT name from store")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach($list as $name){
    echo $name;
}
```

and remember that unlike yours, this function could be used with ANY query returns ANY type of result with better error reporting and many other benefits.

I wrote an article that explains all the drawbacks of your Db class, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes) which is definitely worth to read. You are welcome to ask any questions.